# What was Mohenjo-Daro's "lower town"?

Tags: archaeology, ancient-india

I was reading about Mohenjo-daro sites in current day Pakistan.

The text talked about something called "lower town". What is lower town in that context?

> "Kalibangan is situated on the left bank of the river Ghaggar in Rajasthan. There is same pattern of planning as at Mohenjo-daro and Harappa. There is a citadel on the West side and a ***lower town*** on the east."

SOURCE: Above excerpt is taken from the book titled "Ancient India", by V. D. Mahajan, S Chand Publications.

Comment: What were you reading? Please supply the context of the phrase.

Comment: I have edited my question as suggested. Please refer to the question.

Comment: Since you're so reluctant to share context, _lower town_ is mainly residential as opposed to _upper_ which was for their citadel/acropolis. Look up "**Indus valley or Harappan Architecture and Town Planning**".

Comment: I was reading a book titled "Ancient India" by V. D. Mahajan, S Chand Publications.

Comment: Unless you provide how the section is described, I don't think you can get a proper answer. Mohenjo Daro and Harappa were not fortified towns.

Comment: Well I'm seeing that there is something considered to be a citadel, and the terminology pops up on Google autofill: https://www.google.com/search?q=mohenjo+daro+citadel+and+lower+town&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US752&oq=mohenjo+daro+citadel+a&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.4398j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pattern in towns that have grown around a fortress, in many cultures. The fortress is placed on a hill, since that makes attacking it harder.

People migrate to the area, since anyone who can build a fortress has money, and get jobs there, or run businesses that sell to the fortress inhabitants. A town gradually appears, but there isn't room for it on the hill, so it is on lower ground. Hence a "Lower town."

Edit: The same process also happens for un-fortified towns built on hilltops. It is a bit slower, because the town tends to grow incrementally down the hill, but you still end up with upper and lower parts of the town.

Comment: Oh! I get that.

Comment: Mohenjo Daro and Harappa were not fortified. It did have some towers.